# Deploying website locally and Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin on chrome?

Tags: jquery, xml, google-chrome

I have a client that wants to have a small database application on DVD that runs offline. Rather than having a PHP/MySQL that runs as a standalone/embedded application on a DVD, I want to use an xml database file as the basis of my application. The problem that I am currently facing lies in the fact that Access-Control-Allow-Origin error is shown on chrome if the application is running on locally.

Can you think about an alternative to get over the problem? Other approaches to implement the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to use any web server emulator (e.g php one as winamp) as browser don't let you access local file

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are rather restricted in this case. If you're offline, then you need a database on the client. Normal browsers such as Chrome do not allow you do access the file system (think of the security implications if any website can access your file system). Thus, you really need a database to be running.

Luckily, there's an HTML5 client based database option: http://blog.darkcrimson.com/2010/05/local-databases/